# How could I find the cut off point at both side of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose there is a numpy array: `a = np.array([a0, a1, a2, ...., an])`, and there is a cutoff number. I want to find out the index where the sum before or after which is just-larger than the cut off value. `np.sum(a[:id1]) > value` and `np.sum(a[id2:]) > value`. How could I do this?

For example, the array is `a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,2,4])` and the cutoff value is 7. Thus the index would be 3(1+2+3+4 > 7) and 5(6+2+4 >7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`np.cumsum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html).

```py
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,2,4])

np.argwhere(np.cumsum(a) >= 7)[0]

# where is the first value where cumulative sum is larger than 7
```

```py
Out[47]: array([3], dtype=int64)
```

`3` is the index right after it becomes `>7`.

To start from the end, as you asked, just reverse the array:

```py
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,2,4])

a.shape - np.argwhere(np.cumsum(a[::-1]) >= 7)[0] - 1
```

```py
Out[48]: array([5], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: To add to this: if the values are non-negative, you could use `np.searchsorted` with both the threshold value and `cumsum(a)[-1] - threshold` in order to efficiently find both breakpoints.